# PyCharm - Automate setting Python interpretor for a New Project

Tags: python, user-interface, path, pycharm, interpreter

Ok, so I've been coding python for under a year now. I'm starting to get good at it, and I'm learning about new and awesome modules and libraries. i even made my own remote Pc controller (so basically one PC can control mouse of another PC). Then I found out about PyCharm and how it can load many libraries and work on different projects on the same time, and blah blah blah. So i give it a shot and it's AWESOME. But there is only one problem. Setting a freaking python interpreter. I go to settings and set it to python, and then it works fine... But then when I'm done and i want to open a new project, I see the name of the last project i was working on, and when i press run. it runs the last project! So i have to change the configurations all over again. I remove the old one and set a new configurarion. And the it works. I know this is alot of rambling so to put it in a nutshell.

- I'm using pycharm and set the default interpreter to python (so please don"t say that i have to set a default interpreter from settings)
- Every time i load a new project i get the configurations of the old one. so i 
  have to manually remove those configurations and add the configurations of the new project.
- And so my question is : How can i make PyCharm automate these configurations? How can i just be able to simply open a new project and work on it without having to mess with configurations and interpretors and this stuff..?

I am 100% percent sure this is my misunderstanding of how to use the program because if this wasn't possible then not so many people would be using PyCharm.

And finally. Here are some screenshots of my problem.

1.) I load up my first project in pycharm
[image: 1.) I load up my first project in pycharm]
2.) I close the project to load up a new one
[image: 2.) I close the project to load up a new one]
3.) Here is the new project. This is a pygame one. However as you can see on the top right where the name is displayed, the old project is still there
[[image: 3.) Here is the new project. This is a pygame one. However as you can see on the top right where the name is displayed, the old project is still there[3]]
4.) And when i try to run the program. It runs the old project that i had open before instead
[[image: 4[4]]
5.) This is what it should do.
[image: 5]
6.) So to get it to do actually run the right thing i have to manually change its configuration EVERY TIME
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

And then it works. How can i save myself and run my programs the same way i run them in normal python. Please help me and thanks for being patient on my continuous blabbering and my long explanations. If there is anything you want to know or there is something you don't understand Please comment below

Comment: PyCharm has an option to create new projects and merge with currently opened projects. I'm not sure this is your case, since the projects are in separate folders, but it might be a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want PyCharm to "automatically" change your run configuration when you jump between projects, **DO NOT** close the previous project, just do:

File > Open > On the new window choose your project > On the pop up named `Open Project` choose the `Open in current window` option (although both options will auto-change the run configuration). You are done!

Differently (semi-auto): 
While you have your new project's file open in your editor:

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>. In the popup window choose Tic Tac Toe (most probably it will be the only choice) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That should change the configuration.